# Is it possible to login to a Linux machine with AD credentials without the machine being member of the AD?

Tags: linux, pam, ldap, active-directory, openldap

I'm asking because as far as I know this is not possible with Windows machines since it's mandatory that a Windows machine is known to the AD in order to login with AD credentials.

Is it possible to achieve that with Linux machines through LDAP?